# login script redirects even wrong password entered

Tags: php, mysql

I am sorry if you find this question similar with any other, but i already checked and cannot find appropriate solution. My login-check script seems to have problems because it directs to the login-success page even though i entered wrong password, but i cannot find where. Please help me. Here is the code:

```
<?php

session_start();

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("planner")or die("cannot select DB");


$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['username']);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['password']);


$sql="SELECT username,password FROM members WHERE username='$myusername'";



if($result=mysql_query($sql)){
    $found_user=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0){

$_SESSION['myusername']=true; 
header("location:login_success.php");
}

else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
}
?>

updated script:

<?php

session_start();

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("planner")or die("cannot select DB");


$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['username']);
$mypassword = md5(mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['password']));


$sql="SELECT username,password FROM members WHERE username='$myusername' AND password='$mypassword'";




if($result=mysql_query($sql)){
    $found_user=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)!=0){

$_SESSION['myusername']=true; 
header("location:login_success.php");
}

else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
}
?>



 now it always says wrong username and password entered even though
    with right username and password entered. And here is the login form:


<form method="post" action="check_login.php">
    <p><input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username"></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>

    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></p>
  </form>
```

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: Where do you think your code checks the password?

Comment: [`MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (`mysql_*` functions) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (`mysqli_*` functions) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Password checking not there :)

Comment: after i add the password checking now it always says wrong username and password even though right username and password has been entered. what am i suppose to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are just checking username not both

```
$sql="SELECT username,password FROM members 
WHERE username='$myusername' AND password = '$mypassword'";
```

You have to convert the password with SALT and have to check.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="SELECT username,password FROM members WHERE username='$myusername'";
```

should be

```
$sql="SELECT username,password FROM members WHERE username='$myusername' AND 
password='$mypassword'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't check for password.

```
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['username']);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['password']);

$sql="SELECT username,password FROM members WHERE username='$myusername' 
      AND password='$mypassword'";
```

And your logic should be like:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result and mysql_num_rows($result)){
       $_SESSION['myusername']=true; 
       header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not checked the password and also you have not checked for CASE of user name and password.

Try this query :-

```
SELECT username,password FROM members WHERE binary username='$myusername' and binary password ='$mypassword'
```

Use `binary` to check case sensitiveness of user name and password.
Hope it will help you also to check case sensitive of user name and password.